# Finding non-smoking restaurants in Japan

Tags: japan, restaurants, smoking

In Japan, some restaurants and cafes have designated smoking seating (separate areas or floors), some are fully non-smoking and some are fully smoking.

A few times we've found a nice looking restaurant online or in the hotel advertising, only to find out it was fully smoking.

When searching for a place to eat online (or checking an advertised or recommended one), how do I filter out smoking venues?

Google Maps lists restaurants but doesn't explicitly say whether they are smoking or not.

Comment: Note that even if the establishment is fully non-smoking, it is common that some uneducated smokers go outside smoking and then come back, and you get third-hand smoke.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Gurunavi](https://r.gnavi.co.jp/)**, one of the main Japanese restaurant booking sites, has an option to filter for "completely non-smoking restaurants" (店内全面禁煙).  Sample for Shinjuku, Tokyo:

https://r.gnavi.co.jp/area/aream2115/kods00069/rs/

The catch is that the site is Japanese, and while Gurunavi has an [English version](https://gurunavi.com/en/all/tokyo/am_aream2115?op=kods00069), as far as I can see this option is not available there. (You can filter for "Non-smoking", but this doesn't guarantee they're *fully* non-smoking.)

That said, pictures and Google Translate go a pretty long way for food, and you can also search locations in romanized Japanese.  On desktop, just click in the first dropdown, type in eg "Ginza" and pick the top result to refocus your search there:

[image]

On mobile, click on the search icon, then the box next to map pin to do the same.